# buffer using topological operator

Tags: arcobjects, buffer

```
        IMap map = axMapControl1.ActiveView.FocusMap;
        IFeatureSelection fSelection = map.get_Layer(0) as IFeatureSelection;

        ISelectionSet selSet = fSelection.SelectionSet;


        ICursor cursor;
        selSet.Search(null, true, out cursor);

        IFeature feat = ((IFeatureCursor)cursor).NextFeature();
```

Now i want to create buffer to my cursor.
How can i do it?

Comment: Please explain some more. What kind of buffer do you want

Comment: you can go through this: http://forums.esri.com/thread.asp?c=93&f=983&t=77528

and 

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000019000000

Comment: duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/48307/5850 ? seems the issue is resolved in that question..

Answer (score 1):

You can get your feat geometry and create buffer using Topological operator.
These code can use for you.

```cs
double bufferDistance = 0.0; // Note: set buffer distance as you want. For eg:200 or 500

var featShape = feat.ShapeCopy as IGeometry;

var topologicalOperator = featShape as ITopologicalOperator;
var featureBuffer = topologicalOperator.Buffer(bufferDistance);
```