# How to save buffer created with ArcObjects to a database?

Tags: arcobjects

I have created a buffer as follows

```
IMap map = axMapControl1.ActiveView.FocusMap;
IFeatureSelection fSelection = map.get_Layer(0) as IFeatureSelection;    
ISelectionSet selSet = fSelection.SelectionSet;    
ICursor cursor;
selSet.Search(null, true, out cursor);

IFeature feat = ((IFeatureCursor)cursor).NextFeature();
ITopologicalOperator topoOpr = feat.Shape as ITopologicalOperator;

IPolygon buffPolygon = topoOpr.Buffer(100) as IPolygon;

IActiveView activeView=axMapControl1.ActiveView;
IScreenDisplay screendispaly = activeView.ScreenDisplay;
screendispaly.StartDrawing(screendispaly.hDC, (System.Int32)esriScreenCache.esriAllScreenCaches);    

ISimpleFillSymbol simFillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbolClass() ;
simFillSymbol.Style = esriSimpleFillStyle.esriSFSSolid;
IRgbColor color = new RgbColorClass();
color.Red = 255;
simFillSymbol.Color = color;

ISymbol symbol = simFillSymbol as ISymbol;
screendispaly.SetSymbol(symbol);    
screendispaly.DrawPolygon(buffPolygon);
```

Now I can see a buffer around a feature and I want to save it as a feature class into a database.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//get the featureclass from first layer
IFeatureLayer featureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)map.get_Layer(0)
IFeatureClass featureClass = featureLayer.FeatureClass;
//create a new feature(row)
IFeature feature = featureClass.CreateFeature();
feature.Shape = buffPolygon ;
// Save feature to database
feature.Store();
```

Read [Creating Features](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000049v000000) for detailed descriptions.